# Count the longest chain of 1s in binary number using assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have to count the longest chain of 1s in binary representation of a number, just like the title says. To test I've taken number

```
0x38F9
```

which binary represantation is

```
0011 1000 1111 1001
```

This means my program should write `y=5` as output, indicating that the longest chain of 1s in this number is 5.

I wrote this assembly in C inline, but it outputs `y=15`, not `y=5`, which is clearly wrong:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void){
   short int x, y;
   x = 0x38F9; //x=(0011,1000,1111,1001)
   y = 0;


   asm volatile (
     ".intel_syntax noprefix;"

     "mov ax,%1;"
     "mov cx,16;" //counter of a loop
     "xor dx,dx;" //stores the highest number of 1s in one chain
     "xor bx,bx;" // counter of 1s

     "loop: "
     "shl ax;" 
     "jz reset;"
     "inc bx;" //increment 1s counter
     "cmp bx,dx;" 
     "jg add;"
     "jmp jump;"

     "reset: "
     "xor bx,bx;" 
     "jmp jump;"

     "add: "
     "mov dx, bx;" 

     "jump: "
     "dec cx;" //decrement loop counter
     "jnz loop;"

     "mov %0,dx;"

     ".att_syntax prefix;"

     : "=r" (y)
     : "r" (x)
     : "ax","bx","cx","dx"


   );

   printf("y = %hd",y);


 }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. As I said, it outputs `y=15` which is definitely not true. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Jeez, who writes such inline assembly!? Use a seperate assembly file or only assembly.

Comment: Have you considered writing the function in a higher-level language first? It's a lot easier to reason about something like C, and still easy to translate to assembly.

Comment: @cad: I just started to learning assembly so I don't know this is such a big problem. I'll do this next time.

Comment: `jz reset` <-- did you mean to check the bit that was shifted out? if so, that should've been `jnc`.

Comment: ...and do something about your comments! `"mov dx, bx;" //I move bx to dx` is hardly informative. I can see that you move bx to dx, but why?

Comment: Please don't annotate your assembler describing what instructions do, such as `"inc bx;" //Increment bx`, but use them to give added value beyond what the instruction does, for example `"inc bx;" //Increment bit count`

Comment: @Micheal I just try your solution and it works but I don't understand why. "JZ reset" goes to reset when the result of the last operation was 0, right? So why it is wrong?

Comment: it's because `shl ax` moves the next bit into the carry, where you test it with `jnc`. The test `jz` tests what left in `ax` afterwards.

Comment: `shl ax,1` sets the Z flag based on the new value of `ax`. The bit you shifted out ends up in the C flag.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry I should do as you say. It's difficult for me to describe what I've mean by this code because english is not my mother tongue. I'll try me best next time and I'll try to fix this question.

Comment: The point is if you don't know what an instruction does it can be looked up in a manual: your intentions cannot.

Comment: I really thank you guys for all the help and tips you just gave me. I really appreciate it and I'm sorry for all mistakes I've made. Thank you once again!

Comment: @SuperM4n, don't be discouraged by the negative comments - everyone was amateur once ;)   Thank you for attempting the problem before asking us, and **thank you** for posting a clear question with demo code.